# How do I get my game to run properly (battle system)?

Tags: ruby

As a beginner learning to program, it is extremely helpful to have such a supportive community out there!

I am having trouble getting this 'sample' game working. I am trying to develop a battle system where the player comes across opponents as they progress through a number of rooms. For some reason, when I run it on command prompt, it simply displays "you died" then exits. I am not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Player 
  attr_accessor :hit_points, :attack_power

  def initialize(hit_points, attack_power)
    @hit_points = hit_points
    @attack_power = attack_power
  end 

  def alive?
    @hit_points < 1
    death
  end 

  def hurt 
    @hit_points -= Opponent.attack_power
  end 

  def print_status 
    puts "*" * 80 
    puts "HP: #{hit_points}/#{MAX_HIT_POINTS}"
    puts "*" * 80 
  end
end

class Death 
  puts "You died"
  exit(1)
end 

class Opponent 
  def initialize (hit_points, attack_power)
    @hit_points = hit_points 
    @attack_power = attack_power
    puts "you come across this awful opponent"
  end 

  def alive?
    @hit_points < 1
    death 
  end 

  def hurt 
    @hit_points -= player.attack_power
  end 

  def interact(player)
    while player.alive?
      hurt
      break if @hit_points < 1
      alive?
    end

    if player.alive?
      print "You took #{player_damage_taken} damage and dealt #{player_damage_done} damage, killing your opponent."
      room
    else 
      death
    end 
  end
end

class Room
  puts "you are now in the scary room, and you see an opponent!"

  puts "You come accross a weaker opponent. It is a fish."
  puts "Do you want to (F)ight or (L)eave?"

  action = $stdin.gets.chomp

  if action.downcase == "f"
    fish = Opponent.new(2, 1)
    fish.interact 
  else 
    death
  end 
end 

Player.new(200, 1)
Room.new

class Engine
end
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Ruby, but the Death class has no inner wrapper around the print + exit statements, so those may be called automatically when loading the Death Class. I'd wrap those two statements in a method within the Death class. i.e. `def death *insert puts and exit here*`

Comment: It's very hard to follow what this is doing without indentation. Could you fix the formatting please?

Answer (score 2):

This is breaking because Death is a class and all the code within it is in the *body* of the class. That means this code will be executed when the class is defined, not at the time that `death` is called.

You haven't defined a method named `death`.

Because the `Death` class is tiny, and it would be awkward to name a method within it that stops the game (Death.death, Death.die, Death.run, Death.execute... Not great), and you don't need any of the advantages of a class (such as multiple instances or attributes stored in instance variables), I suggest you make the `death` action a part of the `Player` class.

```
class Player

  # ...

  def die
    puts "You died"
    exit(1)
  end

end
```

Then when you've called `death` (the currently undefined method) Replace it with `player.die`.

As noted by @Kennycoc, you'll need to define a method for the death of an enemy, too.

Comment: Note you will also have to do the same to the opponent class

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like you're under the impression that the code in the top level of the class is run when the class is instantiated (`Class.new`). This is not the case! Everything in the top level of the class is run as it is defined.

The simplest fix to get this running would be to add all the code in your top level of each class under a method named `initialize` this is what's run when the class is instantiated.

Also, you're using your `Death` class as if it were a method. You could either change it from `class Death` to `def death` or change your calls to `Death.new` after moving the code to the `initialize` method (this is not a normal pattern, but would work).